# Empty space in HTML after PHP processing, how can I do it better

Tags: php, html, wordpress

That are the lines rendered in HTML:

```
    <a href='http://www.1stheme.dev/?frontiles=1946'>
<article class="post-1946 frontiles type-frontiles status-publish hentry Width_1_Height_1 "         style="width:326px;height:326px;text-align:left;"
            id="post-1946">



    <header>
    <p class="counter">1 </p>

        <h2 style="">

        Title       </h2>

        <h4 style="">
                </h4>
    </header>
                <div class="frontile_hover Width_1_Height_1" 
            style="width:326px;height:326px;" id="post-1946">
                    </div>

</article>
</a>
```

An this is the PHP that generates them:

```
    <?php echo "<a href='"; if ($disable_link) {
        echo "#' style='cursor:default'>";
            } elseif ($custom_link) { 
        echo $custom_link . "'>";
            }  else  {
        echo $acf_permalink . "'>"; }
?>

<article <?php post_class($tile_dimension . ' ' . $shape); ?>
            style="<?php
                if ($invisible_tile) {echo "visibility:collapse" . ";";}
                        if ($custom_tile_width) {echo "width:" . $custom_tile_width . "px;";}
                        if (!$custom_tile_width && $tiles_units_width && $GLOBALS['acf_grid_width']) {
                            $custom_tile_width = $tiles_units_width * $GLOBALS['acf_grid_width'] + $GLOBALS['acf_grid_margin'] * ($tiles_units_width -1);
                                echo "width:" . $custom_tile_width . "px;";}
                        if ($custom_tile_height) {echo "height:" . $custom_tile_height . "px;";}
                        if (!$custom_tile_height && $tiles_units_height_ && $GLOBALS['acf_grid_height']) {
                            $custom_tile_height = $tiles_units_height_ * $GLOBALS['acf_grid_height'] + $GLOBALS['acf_grid_margin'] * ($tiles_units_height_ -1);
                                echo "height:" . $custom_tile_height . "px;";}                      
                if ($text_font_alignment) {echo "text-align:" . $text_font_alignment . ";";}
                if ($background_color || $background_image) {
                    echo "background:" . $background_color . " url(" . $background_image . ") center/cover;";}

                    ?>"
            id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php if (!$invisible_tile) : ?>



    <header>
    <p class="counter"><?php echo $wp_query->current_post +1; ?> </p>
        <?php // the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'th')); ?>

        <h2 style="<?php
                if ($title_font_color) {echo "color:" . $title_font_color . ";";}
                if ($title_font_size) {echo "font-size:" . $title_font_size . ";";}
                if ($title_margin) {echo "margin:" . $title_margin . ";";}
                if ($title_font_family) {echo "font-family:" . $title_font_family . ";";}
                if ($title_line_height) {echo "line-height:" . $title_line_height . ";";}
                if( is_array($title_font_style) && in_array( 'bold', $title_font_style ) ) {
                    echo "font-weight:bold;"; }
                if( is_array($title_font_style) && in_array( 'italic', $title_font_style ) ) {
                    echo "font-style:italic;"; }
                if ($title_letter_spacing) {echo "letter-spacing:" . $title_letter_spacing . ";";}

                    ?>">

        <?php if ($alternative_title) {echo $alternative_title;} else {the_title();} ?>
        </h2>

        <h4 style="<?php
                if ($desc_font_color) {echo "color:" . $desc_font_color . ";";}
                if ($desc_font_size) {echo "font-size:" . $desc_font_size . ";";}
                if ($desc_margin) {echo "margin:" . $desc_margin . ";";}
                if ($desc_font_family) {echo "font-family:" . $desc_font_family . ";";}
                if ($desc_line_height) {echo "line-height:" . $desc_line_height . ";";}
                if( is_array($title_font_style) && in_array( 'bold', $title_font_style ) ) {
                    echo "font-weight:bold;"; }
                if( is_array($title_font_style) && in_array( 'italic', $title_font_style ) ) {
                    echo "font-style:italic;"; }
                if ($desc_letter_spacing) {echo "letter-spacing:" . $desc_letter_spacing . ";";}1

                    ?>">
        <?php if ($alternative_desc) {echo $alternative_desc;} else {the_excerpt();} ?>
        </h4>
    </header>
        <?php if (!$disable_on_over) : ?>
        <div class="frontile_hover <?php echo $tile_dimension ?>" 
            style="<?php
             if ($hover_bkg_color || $hover_bkg_img) {
                echo "background:" . $hover_bkg_color . " url(" . $hover_bkg_img . ") center/cover;";}
                        if ($custom_tile_width) {echo "width:" . $custom_tile_width . "px;";}
                        if (!$custom_tile_width && $tiles_units_width && $GLOBALS['acf_grid_width']) {
                            $custom_tile_width = $tiles_units_width * $GLOBALS['acf_grid_width'] + $GLOBALS['acf_grid_margin'] * ($tiles_units_width -1);
                                echo "width:" . $custom_tile_width . "px;";}
                        if ($custom_tile_height) {echo "height:" . $custom_tile_height . "px;";}
                        if (!$custom_tile_height && $tiles_units_height_ && $GLOBALS['acf_grid_height']) {
                            $custom_tile_height = $tiles_units_height_ * $GLOBALS['acf_grid_height'] + $GLOBALS['acf_grid_margin'] * ($tiles_units_height_ -1);
                                echo "height:" . $custom_tile_height . "px;";}      
            ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php echo the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; // end disable_on_mouse over?>
    <?php endif; // end invisible_tile?>

</article>
</a>
```

This code works, but It renders with so much white spaces.
Any help is welcome.

I dont have too much to say..., Im using Advanced Custom fields with wordpress to built a customizable theme. Sorry for all the code but in this way you can check it better I think.

Comment: Use the Enter key on the keyboard to align the whitespace to your liking.

Comment: If you break a line in PHP it will show a line break in the source code. HTML treats more than one space and line breaks not created by `<br />` as a single space. If I want beautiful source code I usually concatenate everything to a variable then echo it later.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the white-spaces found between `?>` and `<?php`. Note that removing white-spaces within PHP tags does not change the HTML.

```
<?php echo "<a href='"; if ($disable_link) {
        echo "#' style='cursor:default'>";
            } elseif ($custom_link) { 
        echo $custom_link . "'>";
            }  else  {
        echo $acf_permalink . "'>"; }
?><article <?php post_class($tile_dimension . ' ' . $shape); ?>style="<?php
                if ($invisible_tile) {echo "visibility:collapse" . ";";}
                        if ($custom_tile_width) {echo "width:" . $custom_tile_width . "px;";}
                        if (!$custom_tile_width && $tiles_units_width && $GLOBALS['acf_grid_width']) {
                            $custom_tile_width = $tiles_units_width * $GLOBALS['acf_grid_width'] + $GLOBALS['acf_grid_margin'] * ($tiles_units_width -1);
                                echo "width:" . $custom_tile_width . "px;";}
                        if ($custom_tile_height) {echo "height:" . $custom_tile_height . "px;";}
                        if (!$custom_tile_height && $tiles_units_height_ && $GLOBALS['acf_grid_height']) {
                            $custom_tile_height = $tiles_units_height_ * $GLOBALS['acf_grid_height'] + $GLOBALS['acf_grid_margin'] * ($tiles_units_height_ -1);
                                echo "height:" . $custom_tile_height . "px;";}                      
                if ($text_font_alignment) {echo "text-align:" . $text_font_alignment . ";";}
                if ($background_color || $background_image) {
                    echo "background:" . $background_color . " url(" . $background_image . ") center/cover;";}

                    ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php if (!$invisible_tile) : ?><header>
    <p class="counter"><?php echo $wp_query->current_post +1; ?></p><?php // the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'th')); ?><h2 style="<?php
                if ($title_font_color) {echo "color:" . $title_font_color . ";";}
                if ($title_font_size) {echo "font-size:" . $title_font_size . ";";}
                if ($title_margin) {echo "margin:" . $title_margin . ";";}
                if ($title_font_family) {echo "font-family:" . $title_font_family . ";";}
                if ($title_line_height) {echo "line-height:" . $title_line_height . ";";}
                if( is_array($title_font_style) && in_array( 'bold', $title_font_style ) ) {
                    echo "font-weight:bold;"; }
                if( is_array($title_font_style) && in_array( 'italic', $title_font_style ) ) {
                    echo "font-style:italic;"; }
                if ($title_letter_spacing) {echo "letter-spacing:" . $title_letter_spacing . ";";}

                    ?>"><?php if ($alternative_title) {echo $alternative_title;} else {the_title();} ?>
        </h2><h4 style="<?php
                if ($desc_font_color) {echo "color:" . $desc_font_color . ";";}
                if ($desc_font_size) {echo "font-size:" . $desc_font_size . ";";}
                if ($desc_margin) {echo "margin:" . $desc_margin . ";";}
                if ($desc_font_family) {echo "font-family:" . $desc_font_family . ";";}
                if ($desc_line_height) {echo "line-height:" . $desc_line_height . ";";}
                if( is_array($title_font_style) && in_array( 'bold', $title_font_style ) ) {
                    echo "font-weight:bold;"; }
                if( is_array($title_font_style) && in_array( 'italic', $title_font_style ) ) {
                    echo "font-style:italic;"; }
                if ($desc_letter_spacing) {echo "letter-spacing:" . $desc_letter_spacing . ";";}1

                    ?>"><?php if ($alternative_desc) {echo $alternative_desc;} else {the_excerpt();} ?></h4>
    </header><?php if (!$disable_on_over) : ?><div class="frontile_hover <?php echo $tile_dimension ?>" style="<?php
             if ($hover_bkg_color || $hover_bkg_img) {
                echo "background:" . $hover_bkg_color . " url(" . $hover_bkg_img . ") center/cover;";}
                        if ($custom_tile_width) {echo "width:" . $custom_tile_width . "px;";}
                        if (!$custom_tile_width && $tiles_units_width && $GLOBALS['acf_grid_width']) {
                            $custom_tile_width = $tiles_units_width * $GLOBALS['acf_grid_width'] + $GLOBALS['acf_grid_margin'] * ($tiles_units_width -1);
                                echo "width:" . $custom_tile_width . "px;";}
                        if ($custom_tile_height) {echo "height:" . $custom_tile_height . "px;";}
                        if (!$custom_tile_height && $tiles_units_height_ && $GLOBALS['acf_grid_height']) {
                            $custom_tile_height = $tiles_units_height_ * $GLOBALS['acf_grid_height'] + $GLOBALS['acf_grid_margin'] * ($tiles_units_height_ -1);
                                echo "height:" . $custom_tile_height . "px;";}      
            ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php echo the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        <?php endif; // end disable_on_mouse over?><?php endif; // end invisible_tile?></article>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you I'm goin to try later and I will write back. But I have been thinking taht maybe create a function (using it from functions.php) would be more clean ? I'm sorry, I'm trying but Im not programmer I'm web designer for many years but not at this level, thank you. An example of a function or some solution more clean than this would be helpfull